# RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0' .... The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: dll, com, registry, regasm

I have two dll's that I need to register to enable an API for a third party software I use. This software was recently updated and when I installed the new version and needed to unregister the old dll's and re-register the new ones. In the past, I followed the instructions which were to use regasm with the command below.

```
regasm "path\to\file" /register /tlb /codebase
```

The problem is that with this latest update, when I run that command now I get the following error.

```
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

When I try to look this error up, I mainly get answers for people who are compiling their own librarys or code using visual studio or something like that, not for someone just trying to register a dll someone else made.

I also saw an indication that I might need to use regsvr32.exe instead of regasm.exe. I tried that but for one, I saw that regsvr32.exe can not create a tlb and I end up getting an error saying "The module was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found".

I tried installing the .NET 6.0 SDK and restarting my computer but that didn't work either.

I was wondering if anyone else had an idea why I am getting this error now and if there is anything I can do to solve it?

Comment: Your newer file version seems to be using .NET Core 6. You can't use regasm (from .NET Framework 4.8) on a .NET Core dll. When compiled, a .NET core COM dll also comes with a `<myDll>.comhost.dll`, you must use regsvr32 on this `<myDll>.comhost.dll`. You can forget about regasm and forget about .TLB generation, this is ... gone *"there is no support in .NET Core or .NET 5+ for generating a COM Type Library (TLB) from a .NET assembly"*  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com#embedding-type-libraries-in-the-com-host

Comment: Ok thank you, I was able to register the <myDll>.comhost.dll files. However, I am not sure how to import them into my python scripts. This is probably a separate question, but I used to use clr.AddReference and then import the classes I needed as usual. However, now my python scripts say they cannot find the module...

Comment: Like I said, there's no TLB generated, and your python script may need it. You'll have to either export it as an IDL file to be able to recompile it with MIDL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/midl-start-page) or keep the old .NET Framework version just to create a tlb, but you'll have to think how that will work on the long run